# Legacy encryption in Java and decryption in PHP

Tags: java, php, encryption, aes

I'm trying to encrypt a string using PHP with same result of a legacy Java code.

Java code:

```
public static SecretKeySpec createSecretKey(String mKey) {
    SecretKeySpec secretKey = null;
    MessageDigest sha = null;
    try {
        byte[] key = mKey.getBytes("UTF-8");
        sha = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
        key = sha.digest(key);
        key = Arrays.copyOf(key, 16); // use only first 128 bit
        secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES");
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException ex) {
        System.out.println("- createSecretKey > NoSuchAlgorithmException:" + ex.getMessage());
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException ex) {
        System.out.println("- createSecretKey > UnsupportedEncodingException:" + ex.getMessage());
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println("- createSecretKey > Exception:" + ex.getMessage());
    }
    return secretKey;
}

public static String encryptAES(String stringToEncrypt, SecretKeySpec secretKey) {        //Rijndael
    String encryptedString = null;
    try {
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey);
        encryptedString = Base64.encodeBase64String(cipher.doFinal(stringToEncrypt.getBytes("UTF-8")));
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println("- encryptAES > Exception: " + ex.getMessage());
    }
    return encryptedString;
}
```

Now I want to obtain same result with PHP.

For example:

- key => 1234
- input string => oneString
- desidered output string => whx4s8e6p1erYtsIaFO7qA==

I do this PHP code but result is wrong.

```
$key = "Cup45ZD7";
$o = "19uzJrsE";
echo getEncrypt(pkcs5_pad($o,16),$key) ;

function pkcs5_pad ($text, $blocksize)
{
    $pad = $blocksize - (strlen($text) % $blocksize);
    return $text . str_repeat(chr($pad), $pad);
}

function getEncrypt($sStr, $sKey) {
    return base64_encode(
        mcrypt_encrypt(
            MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128,
            ($sKey),
            $sStr,
            MCRYPT_MODE_ECB
        )
    );
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the same key derivation:

1. Get SHA-1 hash from the "key"
2. Use the first 16 bytes of the hash as the actual key

The following change produces the desired result

```
echo getEncrypt(pkcs5_pad($o, 16), substr(sha1($key, true), 0, 16));
```